# How to Sum Columns of a Multi-Dimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-column, array-sum

I have array data like :

```
[
    'A1' => [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'A2' => [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'A3' => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

I want to add the column values and produce a flat array of sums.

I want answer like this:

```
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Are there any array functions in php to do this? Otherwise how can I do this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: There is no function in PHP that will do this automatically, but two loops should do it. Have a go yourself.

Comment: Related: [Sum each column of a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28128398/2943403)

Comment: Also related: [Calculate totals for each column of a two dimensional array (matrix)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18768541/2943403) and [Get sum of arrays inside array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53150004/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always custom code:

```
function array_sum_rows($arr) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($arr as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $i => $val) {
            $out[$i] = isset($out[$i]) ? $out[$i] + $val : $val;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am getting undifined offset error at line $out[$i] = $out[$i] ? $out[$i] + $val : $val;

Answer (score 0):

```
$multiArray = ... //your array
$sumArray = array();
$i = 1;

foreach ($multiArray as $key => $array) {
    $sumArray[$i] = array_sum($array);
    $i++;
}
```

This would work with your array. You will get an array

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: This sums the values by their parent array, the OP wanted the sum of the values by key.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately loses the actual index in the transpose:

```
function array_transpose($arr) {
    return call_user_func_array(
        'array_map',
        array_merge(
            array(NULL),
            $arr
        )
    );
}

$transposedArray = array_transpose($myData);
$result = array_map('array_sum', $transposedArray);
var_dump($result);
```

But the indexes can be restored by

```
$result = array_combine(array_keys(end($myData)), $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Transpose" the input array (rotate the data 90 degrees so that columns become rows), then feed the new "rows" to `array_map()` so that each has `array_sum()` called upon it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SZbEP))

```
$array = [
    'A1' => [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'A2' => [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'A3' => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var_export(
    array_map(
        'array_sum', 
        array_map(
            null,
            ...array_values($array)
        )
    )
);
```

Or with fewer function calls / cycles: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ds827))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$col) => array_sum($col),
         ...array_values($array)
    )
);
```

*Calling `array_values()` is necessary before the spread operator (`...`) until using a php version that doesn't choke on string keys.

Produces flat output array: `[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`