# Get sum of arrays inside array

Tags: php, laravel

How do I get the **sum** of this arrays.

```
$arrays = [[0, 176000], [0,500], [0, 3960000]];
```

The **output** should be:

```
$arrays = [0, 4136500];
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: your array is wrong otherwise your output is not right!

Comment: What do you mean wrong?

Comment: `,` is elements delimiter in array. Numbers don't use it.

Comment: Okay already updated my arrays.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Using variadic arguments and `null` callback for first `array_map`:

```
$arrays = [[0, 176000], [0,500], [0, 3960000]];
print_r(array_map('array_sum', array_map(null, ...$arrays)));
```

Comment: Im getting this error:  "array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given"

Comment: @u_mulder I used return instead of print_r.

Comment: As @Nick provides a __working__ fiddle, then I suppose you showed us not correct data or applied my code wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In Larevel you can use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections). For example:

```
    $a = collect([[0, 176000], [0,500], [0, 3960000]]);
    $b = new Collection;
    foreach ($a as $k => $e) {
        $b->push ( $a->pluck($k)->sum() );
    }

    $c = $b->take(2); // Result is going to be here
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'am getting 3 items [ 0, 4136500, 0 ]. It should be [ 0, 4136500 ]

Comment: However the $b->take(2) would be dynamic I can take 3

Comment: In your case try to use `$c = $b->take($e->count());` in loop.

Comment: the $e is out of scope?

Answer (score 0):

this is using native way (but i think need to rework)

```
<?php
$arrays = [[0, 176000], [0,500], [0, 3960000]];
$new_arrays = [];
foreach ($arrays as $key => $val) {
  $new_arrays[0] += $val[0];
  $new_arrays[1] += $val[1];
}
print_r($new_arrays);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think so because the array index should be dynamic.

Comment: can you more specific on what do want to achieve? @Jearson

Comment: $ilubis what if I have [[0,17600, 200]]

Answer (score 0):

U_mulders answer works if there is no keys to to keep track of.

If you have an associative array then you need to loop the array and build add the values like:

```
$arrays = [[0,"A" => 176000], [0, "b" => 500], [0, 3960000, 200], [10, 500, 200]];

foreach($arrays as $sub){
    foreach($sub as $key => $num){
        if(!isset($new[$key])) $new[$key] =0;
        $new[$key] += $num;
    }
}
var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(10)
  ["A"]=>
  int(176000)
  ["b"]=>
  int(500)
  [1]=>
  int(3960500)
  [2]=>
  int(400)
}
```

https://3v4l.org/NbNVg

Comment: Yeah mulder answer is correct for native php but for collections in laravel converting to Array is not working

Comment: @Jearson What are you converting? Your question says nothing about converting

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `array_map()` more than once.  Unpack the array using the spread operator (`...`).  This will deliver columns of data to the custom function's body.  Return the sum of each column.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PkCht))

```
$arrays = [[0, 176000], [0,500], [0, 3960000]];
var_export(
    array_map(fn() => array_sum(func_get_args()), ...$arrays)
);
```

Or

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn(...$col) => array_sum($col), ...$arrays)
);
```

Output (from either)

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 4136500,
)
```